# Run macro between buffers

Tags: buffers, macro

I know there is a possibility to run a macro in multiple buffers using `bufdo`.

However, what I'm not aware, if there is somehow to use a "intercommunicated macro", e.g:

File 1:

```
foo
bar
bun
```

File 2:

```
{
}
```

Some pseudo macro: `ggD(move to buffer 2)o  "^R"": "^R"",(move back to buffer 1)`

The result of such macro would be (after 3 iterations would be):

File 2:

```
{
  "bun": "bun",
  "bar": "bar",
  "foo": "foo",
}
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just put `:b2` and `:b1` in the macro?

Comment: Nooooo way ! Nooooo way. Damn, didn't even think about it ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for completeness's sake (and so that this doesn't get bumped in six months by Community):

You can put a buffer command (`:b`) in macros. For your case:

```
qqggD:b#^Mo^R":b#^Mq
```

Where "#" is the number of the buffer you want to switch to, `^M` is pressing `<Enter>`, and `^R` is pressing `<C-r>`.

See `:h buffer` for more info.